# Problemas ao selecionar

Tags: html, css

Olá! Bom, eu estou com um probleminha... Só que não sei explicar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema é esse que vocês estão vendo na imagem, o tamanho ao selecionar é bem maior do que a fonte... Espero que tenham entendido.

Gostaria de deixar tipo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deixa o `line-height` com o mesmo tamanho do `font-size` ou próximo.

Comment: Mas quando eu deixo do mesmo tamanho do texto, o espaçamento entre a fonte de baixo com a de cima ficam muito juntinhas..

Comment: Deixa aproximadinho um valorzinho até atingir o resultadinho que precisa na seleçãozinha ;)

Comment: Se você colocar o código fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Sua fonte tem o line-height maior do que deveria ser. Caso diminuir o `line-height` não seja agradável para ti, acredito que só editando a fonte.